# Embedded RavenDB and indexing more then 5 new documents

Tags: ravendb

I'm using RavenDB Embedded. Build 888.
Have photos collection:

```
public class Photo
    {
        private Dictionary<string, VoteDictionaryValue> _votes = new Dictionary<string, VoteDictionaryValue>();

        public Photo()
        {
            Created = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; private set; }

        public Dictionary<string, VoteDictionaryValue> Votes
        {
            get { return _votes; }
            protected set { _votes = value; }
        }
}
```

Have index:

```
public class PhotosSortByCreated : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Photo>
    {
        public PhotosSortByCreated()
        {
            Map = photos => from photo in photos
                            select new {photo.Created};

            Store(x => x.Created, FieldStorage.No);
            Sort(x => x.Created, SortOptions.String);
        }
    }
```

and query:

```
RavenQueryStatistics stat;

var query = from photo in RavenSession.Query<Photo>()
                        orderby photo.Created descending
                        select photo;

var result = query.Statistics(out stat).Skip(page*pageSize).Take(pageSize).Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))));
```

Add 10 photos, one by one.

by this query I get only first 5-6.

all new added photos will not returned.

after pool restart I can add 5-6 new photos, before ravenDB stops index them.

all added photos saved in DB, but they are not indexed.

why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
RavenSession.Query<Photo>().Customize(x=>x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
```

What happens?

Comment: I still have the problem. Not all photos was indexed.
They are present in DB but absent in result.
Btw, reproduced only on shared hosting.